# What is the an effective design pattern/style for designing a rule engine in Java?

Tags: java, class, design-patterns, enums, anonymous-class

I am implementing a rule-engine in Java. My rule-engine predefines a list of independent rules and rule sets. A rule here is simply a piece of logic. And a rule set combines these simple rules into an ordered set.

I am a decent java developer but not a Guru. My colleague suggested me two designs for this purpose. I am not satisfied with both the designs, hence this question.

**Example of a Rule in my project:**
Say the inputs are locations in USA for e.g., Santa Barbara, CA, USA or OH, US which is usually in some well defined format with the city, state and country fields. Then I can have some rules as follows:

**RULE 1:** City not null
**RULE 2:** State not null
**RULE 3:** Country equals US or USA
**RULE 4:** State length equals 2

Example of a RuleSet in my project:

**RULESET:** Valid location 
This ruleset is an ordered set of the above defined rules.

The two design templates I have implemented are as follows:

**Design 1: Using Enum with Anonymous Inner classes**

**Rule.java**

```
public interface Rule {
    public Object apply(Object object);
}
```

**NlpRule.java**

```
public enum NlpRule {
    CITY_NOT_NULL(new Rule() {

        @Override
        public Object apply(Object object) {
            String location = (String) object;
            String city = location.split(",")[0];
            if (city != null) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    }),

    STATE_NOT_NULL(new Rule() {

        @Override
        public Object apply(Object object) {
            String location = (String) object;
            String state = location.split(",")[1];
            if (state != null) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    }),

    COUNTRY_US(new Rule() {

        @Override
        public Object apply(Object object) {
            String location = (String) object;
            String country = location.split(",")[2];
            if (country.equals("US") || country.equals("USA")) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    }),

    STATE_ABBREVIATED(new Rule() {

        @Override
        public Object apply(Object object) {
            String location = (String) object;
            String state = location.split(",")[1];
            if (state.length() == 2) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    });

    private Rule rule;

    NlpRule(Rule rule) {
        this.rule = rule;
    }

    public Object apply(Object object) {
        return rule.apply(object);
    }
}
```

**RuleSet.java**

```
public class RuleSet {
    private List<NlpRule> rules;

    public RuleSet() {
        rules = new ArrayList<NlpRule>();
    }

    public RuleSet(List<NlpRule> rules) {
        this.rules = rules;
    }

    public void add(NlpRule rule) {
        rules.add(rule);
    }

    public boolean apply(Object object) throws Exception {
        boolean state = false;
        for (NlpRule rule : rules) {
            state = (boolean) rule.apply(object);
        }
        return state;
    }
}
```

**RuleSets.java**

```
public class RuleSets {
    private RuleSets() {

    }

    public static RuleSet isValidLocation() {
        RuleSet ruleSet = new RuleSet();
        ruleSet.add(NlpRule.CITY_NOT_NULL);
        ruleSet.add(NlpRule.STATE_NOT_NULL);
        ruleSet.add(NlpRule.COUNTRY_US);
        ruleSet.add(NlpRule.STATE_ABBREVIATED);
        return ruleSet;
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String location = "Santa Barbara,CA,USA";
        RuleSet ruleSet = RuleSets.isValidLocation();
        try {
            boolean isValid = (boolean) ruleSet.apply(location);
            System.out.println(isValid);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

**Design 2: Using Abstract Class**

**NlpRule.java**

```
public abstract class NlpRule {

    public abstract Object apply(Object object);

    public final static NlpRule CITY_NOT_NULL = new NlpRule() {
        public Object apply(Object object) {
            String location = (String) object;
            String city = location.split(",")[0];
            if (city != null) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;

        }

    };

    public final static NlpRule STATE_NOT_NULL = new NlpRule() {
        public Object apply(Object object) {
            String location = (String) object;
            String city = location.split(",")[0];
            if (city != null) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;

        }

    };

    public final static NlpRule COUNTRY_US = new NlpRule() {
        public Object apply(Object object) {
            String location = (String) object;
            String country = location.split(",")[2];
            if (country.equals("US") || country.equals("USA")) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;

        }

    };

    public final static NlpRule STATE_ABBREVIATED = new NlpRule() {
        public Object apply(Object object) {
            String location = (String) object;
            String state = location.split(",")[1];
            if (state.length() == 2) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    };

}
```

**RuleSet.java**

```
public class RuleSet {
    private List<NlpRule> rules;

    public RuleSet() {
        rules = new ArrayList<NlpRule>();
    }

    public RuleSet(List<NlpRule> rules) {
        this.rules = rules;
    }

    public void add(NlpRule rule) {
        rules.add(rule);
    }

    public boolean apply(Object object) throws Exception {
        boolean state = false;
        for (NlpRule rule : rules) {
            state = (boolean) rule.apply(object);
        }
        return state;
    }
}
```

**RuleSets.java**

```
import com.hgdata.design.one.NlpRule;
import com.hgdata.design.one.RuleSet;

public class RuleSets {
    private RuleSets() {

    }

    public static RuleSet isValidLocation() {
        RuleSet ruleSet = new RuleSet();
        ruleSet.add(NlpRule.CITY_NOT_NULL);
        ruleSet.add(NlpRule.STATE_NOT_NULL);
        ruleSet.add(NlpRule.COUNTRY_US);
        ruleSet.add(NlpRule.STATE_ABBREVIATED);
        return ruleSet;
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String location = "Santa Barbara,CA,USA";
        RuleSet ruleSet = RuleSets.isValidLocation();
        try {
            boolean isValid = (boolean) ruleSet.apply(location);
            System.out.println(isValid);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

**Better Design Approach/Pattern ?**
As you can see, design 2 gets rid of the interface and enum. It instead uses an abstract class. I am still wondering if there is a better design pattern/approach to implement the same.

**Instantiation using initializer blocks:**

Now in case of both designs above. Say, if I need to instantiate an external class to use it inside my apply logic, then I am forced to use initializer blocks which I am not totally aware whether is a good practice. See example for such a scenario below:

**Design 1:**

```
...
STATE_ABBREVIATED(new Rule() {
        private CustomParser parser;

        {
            parser = new CustomParser();
        }

        @Override
        public Object apply(Object object) {
            String location = (String) object;
            location = parser.parse(location);
            String state = location.split(",")[1];
            if (state.length() == 2) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    });
...
```

**Design 2:**

```
...
public final static NlpRule STATE_ABBREVIATED = new NlpRule() {
        private CustomParser parser;

        {
            parser = new CustomParser();
        }
        public Object apply(Object object) {
            String location = (String) object;
            location = parser.parse(location);
            String state = location.split(",")[1];
            if (state.length() == 2) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    };
...
```

Java experts please cast some light! Also please pinpoint if you find any flaws in the above two designs. I need to know the pros and cons associated with each of the designs to help me make the right decision. I am looking into lambdas, predicates and several other patterns as suggested by some users in the comments.

Comment: Not to be annoying, but why isn't this just a regex problem? Regex is a pretty well developed and tested "ruleset" against strings. Even if you want to split the regexes out into their own objects you could then 1 ) use those objects in an array, 2) ask each of them for their regex 3) compile that into a larger regex (and that can be your ruleset)

Comment: @LLFourm The rules I have shown above are really simplistic. I have over 100 rules which I will need to implement. And most of the rules have complex logic and depend on other classes. This isn't really a regex problem.

Comment: Use JavaCompilerAPI: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html. Cannot say more, I don't know much about java.

Comment: If your *rules* are for validating data only, then use an implementation of [JSR 303](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303), otherwise use a rule engine like drools. Don't try to reinvent the wheel or explain your exact problem / use case to solve and we will help you on that basis.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The rules broadly fall under two types, string cleaning and validation. Most of the rules deal with natural language processing (checking if a string/part of a string is valid, good or bad). Some rules are rather complex since they bunch together a lot of steps (rules) like identifying unescaped html entities in a chunk of text and trying to map it to its respective character etc.. In such cases, the rules are grouped into a rule set and applied on the text or string.

Comment: If that's the case, except for the HTML, sounds like a bunch of regexes to me unless you need to use other ways to *validate* the data contained in the strings e.g. it exists in a specific data source.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes! regex is only a part of the process and I do have a few regex rules. A lot of rules involves looking to different data sources. You are right.

Comment: All of these rules need to be chained? A string must pass for all the rules or are different levels of the result of the validation?

Comment: Effectively its the predicate pattern that you are using

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza For validation rules, its just true or false. In case of false, I throw exceptions and handle them to update counters. With cleaner rules, they are usually chained (orderly) and thats where ruleset come into picture

Comment: Then use [chain of responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) along with [decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) to design your set of rules and the evaluator of the rules.

Comment: @NitinDandriyal Can you point me to some resources

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Can you point me to some resources

Comment: Those links are the resources, they're not for decoration purpose.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Sorry! missed to notice them. Will look into those patterns. Thanks

Comment: @Shankar if you're actually doing NLP you really don't want to reinvent the wheel - check out tools like GATE Developer which come with their own grammar based rule format (that is much more powerful than regex obviously) - jape.

Comment: btw "if(x)return true;else return false;` can be simplified to `return x;`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is exactly what [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
 is for.

Answer (score 8):

This is an interesting question with many possible answers. To some extent the solution is going to depend on personal preference. I have often come across similar problems and have the following recommendations. Note that these work for me but might not suit your needs.

1. Use `enum`. In the long term I feel they have a lot of advantages over `private static` members in terms of their error checking and the useful containers (EnumSet etc.) that can use them efficiently.
2. Use interfaces over abstract classes. Before Java 8 there were useful reasons to use abstract classes. With `default` members there are now no good reasons (just my opinion - I'm sure others will disagree). An enum can implement an interface.
3. In Java 8 the logic associated with each 'rule' can be embedded in a lambda expression which makes the initialization code for your enums clearer.
4. Keep lambdas very short - just one or two commands at the most (and preferably one expression without a block). This means splitting any complex logic into a separate methods.
5. Use separate enums to classify your rules. There's no good reason to put them all into one and by splitting them out you can make the constructors simple by having exactly the lambda expressions relevant to their domain. See my example below to see what I mean.
6. If you have hierarchies of rules, use the composite design pattern. It's flexible and robust.

So putting those recommendations together I would suggest something like:

```
interface LocationRule{
    boolean isValid(Location location);
}

enum ValidValueRule implements LocationRule {
    STATE_NOT_NULL(location -> location.getState() != null),
    CITY_NOT_NULL(location -> location.getCity() != null);

    private final Predicate<Location> locationPredicate;
    ValidValueRule(Predicate<Location> locationPredicate) {
        this.locationPredicate = locationPredicate;
    }

    public boolean isValid(Location location) {
        return locationPredicate.test(location);
    }
}

enum StateSizeRule implements LocationRule {
    IS_BIG_STATE(size -> size > 1000000),
    IS_SMALL_STATE(size -> size < 1000);

    private final Predicate<Integer> sizePredicate;
    StateSize(Predicate<Integer> sizePredicate) {
        this.sizePredicate = sizePredicate;
    }
    public boolean isValid(Location location) {
        return sizePredicate.test(location.getState().getSize());
    }
}

class AllPassRule implements LocationRule {
    private final List<LocationRule > rules = new ArrayList<>();
    public void addRule(LocationRule rule) {
        rules.add(rule);
    }
    public boolean isValid(Location location) {
        return rules.stream().allMatch(rule -> rule.isValid(location));
    }
}

class AnyPassRule implements LocationRule {
    private final List<LocationRule > rules = new ArrayList<>();
    public void addRule(LocationRule rule) {
        rules.add(rule);
    }
    public boolean isValid(Location location) {
        return rules.stream().anyMatch(rule -> rule.isValid(location));
    }
}

class NegateRule implements LocationRule {
    private final Rule rule;
    public NegateRule(Rule rule) {
        this.rule = rule;
    }
    public boolean isValid(Location location) {
        return !rule.isValid(location);
    }
}
```

So, for example, to implement a rule that locations must either be in a city or in a state that isn't small:

```
AnyPassRule cityOrNonSmallState = new AnyPassRule();
cityOrNonSmallState.addRule(ValidValueRule.CITY_NOT_NULL);
cityOrNonSmallState.addRule(new NegateRule(StateSize.IS_SMALL_STATE));
return cityOrNonSmallState.isValid(location);
```

Answer (score 4):

There's lots of (open source) Java rule engines out there already - check out http://java-source.net/open-source/rule-engines & http://drools.org/

You could start with using/examining the source for one of those (taking note of where it doesn't meet your requirements) and go from there.

Comment: Looking at the short-comings of existing implementations (for your particular application) will help you refine your design so that it addresses those short comings. Or even better, an existing implementation works for you and you can move onto something else.

Comment: I did looked into drools and felt it was rather too heavy weight for my problem. I need a really simplistic and effective design since my rules are totally independent of each other and also the idea of having a ruleset makes grouping and applying rules really straight forward.

Comment: @Shankar - There are a bunch more on that page (perhaps one that's sufficiently lightweight). Fair enough if not though.

Answer (score 3):

Interface with static fields:

```
public interface NlpRule 
{
    Object apply(Object object);

    NlpRule CITY_NOT_NULL = object ->
    {
        String location = (String) object;
        String city = location.split(",")[0];
        return ...true/false;
    };

    // etc.
```

Some may prefer methods over functional objects

```
public interface NlpRule 
{
    Object apply(Object object);

    static boolean cityNotNull(Object object) // java8: static method in interface
    {
        String location = (String) object;
        String city = location.split(",")[0];
        return ...true/false;
    };

    // etc. 

}

// use method reference as functional object

NlpRule rule = NlpRule::cityNotNull;

ruleset.add( NlpRule::cityNotNull );
```

Or you could have both method and field

```
public interface NlpRule 
{
    Object apply(Object object);

    NlpRule CITY_NOT_NULL = NlpRule::cityNotNull;
    static boolean cityNotNull(Object object)
    {
        ...
    };
```

---

The example rules are all `String->boolean`, not sure why NlpRule is `Object->Object`. If the rules could indeed accept/return different types, you should probably generify `NlpRule<T,R>`.

---

The CustomParser can be stored in a package-private helper class

```
class NlpRuleHelper
{
    static final CustomParser parser = new CustomParser();
}

--

public interface NlpRule
...
    NlpRule STATE_ABBREVIATED = object -> 
    {
         ...
         location = NlpRuleHelper.parser.parse(location);
```

Answer (score 3):

Another possible answer is to use a DSL parser to valid your rule, in function programming language, there is thing called parser combinator which could build a larger parser(rule set) from different basic parser(rule). The good point of this way is the flexibility, the cons is every time your want to change your rule set, you have to re-code.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have added at least one layer of unnecessary code. Remember that `enum` can also implement interfaces and can even have abstract methods.

```
/**
 * I don't like `Object` so I will adjust.
 */
public interface Rule {

    public boolean pass(String s);
}

/**
 * All pass country codes.
 */
public enum ValidCountry {

    US, USA;
    public static Set<String> all = new HashSet<>();

    static {
        for (ValidCountry c : ValidCountry.values()) {
            all.add(c.name());
        }
    }
}

public enum NlpRule implements Rule {

    CITY_NOT_NULL {

                @Override
                public boolean pass(String location) {
                    return location.split(",")[0] != null;
                }

            },
    STATE_NOT_NULL {

                @Override
                public boolean pass(String location) {
                    return location.split(",")[1] != null;
                }

            },
    COUNTRY_US {
                @Override
                public boolean pass(String location) {
                    return ValidCountry.all.contains(location.split(",")[2]);
                }

            },
    STATE_ABBREVIATED {
                @Override
                public boolean pass(String location) {
                    return location.split(",")[1].length() == 2;
                }

            };
    /**
     * You can even make Sets of them.
     */
    static Set<NlpRule> isValidLocation = EnumSet.of(CITY_NOT_NULL, STATE_NOT_NULL, COUNTRY_US, STATE_ABBREVIATED);
}

public void test() {
    String test = "Santa Barbara,CA,USA";
    for (Rule r : NlpRule.isValidLocation) {
        boolean pass = r.pass(test);
        System.out.println(r + "(\"" + test + "\") - " + (pass ? "passes" : "FAILS"));
    }
}
```